# Mail exception handling in zend framework 2

Tags: exception, zend-framework2, sendmail

I am trying to send an email in zend framework 2 using Mail\Transport\Sendmail().
It is showing a runtime exception on invalid email id.

error message is "Unable to send mail: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.1.1 ... User unknown"

Zend\Mail\Exception\RuntimeException

$options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions($config_setting);

```
    // render Email Content
    $this->renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
    $content = $this->renderer->render($config['mail']['templates']. $messageTemplate, $messageParam);

    // make a header as html
    $html = new MimePart($content);
    $html->type = $config['mail']['content_type'];
    $body = new MimeMessage();
    $body->setParts(array($html,));

    // instance mail
    $mail = new Mail\Message();
    $mail->setBody($body); // will generate our code html from template.phtml
    $mail->setFrom($config['mail']['from_email'],$config['mail']['from_name']);
    $mail->setTo($mailTo);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    //$transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
    $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();

    try{
        $response = @$transport->send($mail);
        return $response;
    }
    catch(Zend\Mail\Exception\RuntimeException $ex)
    {
        $ex->getMessage();
        $response = array('error' => 1, 'msg' => $ex->getMessage());
        //return $response;
    }
```

i want to ignore this exception message.

Comment: Could you post the relevant sendmail log entries?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip :- Unable to send mail: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.1.1 ... User unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two transports, one Sendmail and one SMTP. Sendmail is an internal mail server on your pc, which should work fine. SMTP is a protocol to let an (possible external) mail server send emails. You can use your own SMPT server, or connect to e.g. Google or Hotmail for sending mails over SMTP.

You have this in your code:

```
//$transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
```

So you are using in your *code* the Sendmail transport, but the *exception* is from SMTP:

> Unable to send mail: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.1.1 ... User unknown

So it seems to me you are using the SMTP in your code somewhere accidentally. Switch to the Sendmail and it should work fine, or check your question again with the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks Jurian for you quick reply. i tried the both but its showing the same exception after using Smtp($options),  when email id is invalid.

Comment: Even I tried the same but still am getting the error and even mail is not being send.